# Error Handling while File Updoading via an IFrame

Tags: javascript, jakarta-ee, extjs4

The steps of my application are:

1. a client chooses several files via checkboxes,
2. a request is formed with the files' identifiers,
3. a client downloads the archive via an iframe: (a server finds these files, zips them, and then response is formed containing the zip archive 's bytes)

Here is the code of the iframe:

```
function makeSaveFrame(urlToServer) {
      var ifrm = document.createElement("IFRAME");
      ifrm.setAttribute("style", "display:none;");
      ifrm.setAttribute("src", 'urlToServer';
      ifrm.style.width = "0px";
      ifrm.style.height = "0px";
      document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
}
```

The response's type and header:

```
response.setContentType("application/zip");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachments; filename=\"" + fileName + ".zip\"");
```

The problem is: if something goes wrong, I need to send a reason to a client. As far as I am concerned, an error message must be of JSONObject type.

[if an error occurs on the server I can change the content type of the response and send a JSONObject, but I don't know how to filter the response and even how to catch an event of receiving a response in the iframe]

Please, share an expirience on this issue.

**UPDATE**

if I send

```
response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "testMessage");
```

the **bad response** response arrives, but try/catch block around the makeSaveFrame() method doesn't catch this.

**UPDATRE**
I've tried this

```
var uploadForm = document.createElement('form');
                    uploadForm.name = 'uploadForm';
                    uploadForm.setAttribute("style", "display:none;");
                    document.body.appendChild(uploadForm);

                    Ext.Ajax.request({
                        url: 'requestURL',
                        form: uploadForm.getForm().getEl(),
                        isUpload : true,
                        method: 'post',
                        failure : function() {
                            Ext.MessageBox.show({
                                title   : 'title',
                                msg     : 'message',
                                buttons : Ext.MessageBox.OK
                            });
                        }
                    });
```

but the **isUpload** parameter kills a failure callback. So that, when a server answers with the **bad response** response, no error handler (failure callback) presents.

Comment: As a side note : `ifrm.style.width = "0px";` would be simpler than concatenating... just sayin'

Comment: is there a reason to use an iframe for this? Can you do a regular form submission?

Comment: I'm not sure how to get a response after a form submission. Anyway the problem is how to manage different types of response

Comment: @Dmitry, just a thought, why don't you try a `js/jquery` on 'window.onload' event of the frame, that shall check the response type and accordingly show a message.

Comment: @Furqan, thank you for the idea. I have no expirience in jquery, could you, please, post a snippet?

Comment: Upload is reserved for forms with input type file - meaning that clients will upload their own local files to your server. I don't think this is what you are after. But if you are check out these upload examples: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/form/file-upload.html

Comment: Well, it is true, but in that case how does the last update work? It gets a file from a server and then transfers it to a form. May be I'm wrong, but it seems the form's target is a generated iframe...

Answer (score 0):

Since you have updated you question and not using frame anymore to request the content, you can use jquery, it can be similar to your updated content in question (ExtJS4 part in the end) ,

```
         $.ajax({
                    url: 'requestURL',
                    form: uploadForm.serialize(),
                    method: 'post',                        
                    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        // you can check the jqXHR object properties & methods to check
                        //  the response status and contentType
                        alert("An error occured.");
                    }
                });
```

Hope this helps.For more options on Jquery AJAX request follow [JQuery reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

P.S : you need to add additional jquery library files to your page.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try it in 10 minutes.

Comment: There are some deployment issues. so that it can take a bit longer =)

Comment: @Dmitry, take your time and if it works for you that's great.

Comment: The problem occurred: 'uploadForm.serialize is not a function'

Comment: @Dmitry, try `$("#uploadForm").serialize();` , where i assume you upload form has the same id.

Comment: I've tried form:uploadForm and form:$("form[name=uploadForm]").serialize(), but nothing happens when a response arrives (no download window raises).

Comment: and that is weird that in the FireBug I see a GET request (but I have method: 'POST')...

Answer (score 0):

Please see this [arcticle](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/ajax-style-file-uploading-using-hidden-iframe/). 
It seems that one can manipulate a content after upload, so that it is possible to apply a handler on it. Unfortunately, I had 2 problems in it:

1. in IE, 2 windows open and the second one (iframe) doesn't close after downloading a file (in FF works perfectly)
2. When a response arrives, the content is always empty, and I can't estimate it.

The next idea is to get cookies from the response header (iframe). This solution seems rather promising...